# ploting multiple data series with Macro in excel

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim names1 As String
Dim names2 As String
Dim names3 As String


ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmooth).Select
For i = 1 To 1

    names1 = Cells(2, i + 1).Address
    names2 = Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(85, i)).Address
    names3 = Range(Cells(3, i + 1), Cells(85, i + 1)).Address

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet3!" & names1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet3!" & names2
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet3!" & names3

Next i
```

The X values are in column "I" , the Y values are in column "I+1" 
Now I think in every loop it deletes the existing plot and draw the new one. So what am I supposed to add in order to stack plots over each other?

Comment: You `For` loop is from `1 To 1` ???

Comment: I wanted to make sure that it plots the first set of data and remove it so I change it to "1 to 1" and forgot to copy the correct version here.

Comment: see my answer and code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub PlotMultiSeries()

Dim i           As Long
Dim names1      As String
Dim names2      As String
Dim names3      As String
Dim MyCht       As Shape
Dim Ser         As Series

' axccording to your code, you are using "Sheet3" , fully qualify all your Ranges and Cells
With Worksheets("Sheet3")

    ' set the created Chart to a Shape variable
    Set MyCht = .Shapes.AddChart2(Style:=240, XlChartType:=xlXYScatterSmooth)

    For i = 1 To 1 ' your i loop is from 1 To 1 ???
        names1 = .Cells(2, i + 1).Address(False, False, xlA1, True)
        names2 = .Range(.Cells(3, i), .Cells(85, i)).Address(False, False, xlA1, True)
        names3 = .Range(.Cells(3, i + 1), .Cells(85, i + 1)).Address(False, False, xlA1, True)

        With MyCht
            ' add a new series
            Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            ' define new Series properties
            With Ser
                .Name = "=" & names1
                .XValues = "=" & names2
                .Values = "=" & names3
            End With
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: I changed it a bit as follow
  For i = 2 To 5
    names1 = Cells(2, 2 * i - 1).Address
    names2 = Range(Cells(3, 2 * i - 1), Cells(85, 2 * i - 1)).Address
    names3 = Range(Cells(3, 2 * i), Cells(85, 2 * i)).Address 
for i=1 it sweep through all the columns and plots them (it should only plot the first set and go for next i) but after that it works fine

Comment: @mojijoon glad I could help :) don't forget to mark as "Answer"

Comment: what about the first iteration. how can i change it so it only plot the first set of data?

Comment: @mojijoon you can modify it with changing the `For i = 1 To 1` loop, if you want only the first one, use is like it's the code above, if you want all the columns, you need to specify until which column

Comment: Thanks for the help. this works fine :  For i = 1 To 5
    names1 = Cells(2, 2 * i).Address
    names2 = Range(Cells(3, 2 * i - 1), Cells(85, 2 * i - 1)).Address
    names3 = Range(Cells(3, 2 * i), Cells(85, 2 * i)).Address